# image in not animated in IE, works for other browser?

Tags: asp.net

In ASPX page we have below code, everything works fine, but the animated gif "arrows64.gif" is not animated in IE browser, it's seems like freeze, need to know the workaround?

In page load I'm calling time consuming database call, meanwhile I wanted to show this busy image, but it's freeze in IE,

```
<div id="divLoading" runat="server" style="text-align: center">
    <div style="z-index: 1000; border: medium none; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; width: 100%;
        height: 100%; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6;
        cursor: wait; position: fixed;">
    </div>
    <div style="z-index: 1001; position: fixed; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 30%;
        top: 40%; left: 35%; text-align: center; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 3px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: wait;">
        <img src="Images/arrows64.gif" width="64" height="64" alt="Loading..." />
        <h1>
            Please wait...</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's likely an IE Setting that you need to flip or simply a lack of support for animated GIFs (depending on the version). I wouldn't lose my sleep over this and just use a different image that explicitly says that something is loading... that way, even if it doesn't move, the user can read that it's happening.

If it's a setting that needs to be flipped, your users will be annoyed to learn that they need to change their IE configuration in order for your website to behave properly.

[Read this post](http://www.norio.be/comment/234) for a possible workaround in case you must use this animated GIF.